# JSON/Javascript: return which array object contains a certain property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Given a JSON object such as this:

```
{
  "something": {
    "terms": [
      {
        "span": [
          15,
          16
        ],
        "value": ":",
        "label": "separator"
      },
      {
        "span": [
          16,
          20
        ],
        "value": "12.5",
        "label": "number"
      }
    ],
    "span": [
      15,
      20
    ],
    "weight": 0.005,
    "value": ":12.5"
  }
```

I would like write some javascript that would determine the index of the "term" that has a "label": "number".  Ultimately I want to determine the "value" of the "term" that has a "label": "number",  I know I can get that with something like this, where the index is known:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(result.trim());
var numberValue = parsed.terms[1].value;
```

My first thought is perhaps to just write a foreach loop and then return the numberValue when I arrive at an array object that has "label": "number".

Is there a more elegant and/or concise way to do this?

Comment: [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: What kind of parser produces this Json?

Comment: not sure.  It is a proprietary API.  Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
var numberValue, list = parsed.something.terms.filter(function(a){
  return a.label==='number';
});
numberValue = list.length ? list[0].value : -1;
```

Comment: In Harmony, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: However, with `find` you can't to get all `value` elements, if need.

Comment: Thank you for this.  How would I modify this code to return the array index of the "term" where the "label" = "number"?