# Deriving an array of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a continuation of exploration traversing data structures in JavaScript.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772816/json-javascript-return-index-of-array-object-containing-a-certain-property) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746939/json-javascript-return-which-array-object-contains-a-certain-propertyhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746939/json-javascript-return-which-array-object-contains-a-certain-property).

Given this Javascript object:

```
var parsed =       {
  "terms": [
    {
      "span": [
        12,
        13
      ],
      "value": "2",
      "label": "number"
    },
    {
      "span": [
        13,
        14
      ],
      "value": "x",
      "label": "multiply"
    },
    {
      "span": [
        14,
        16
      ],
      "value": "14",
      "label": "number"
    },
  ],
  "span": [
    12,
    21
  ],
  "weight": 0.85,
  "value": "2x14 test"
};
```

How would I derive an array of the indexes of the terms where the label: number?

In a previous question, noted above, I was able to solve the notion of deriving the index for a certain label, when it was known that there was only one instance of such.

```
parsed.terms.map(function(d){ return d['label']; }).indexOf('number');
```

Now I am faced with the notion of multiple instances, as in the object above. The above code snip will only derive the index of the first.

I could build an array by looping through the terms and see if each has a number label, however the ideal solution would perhaps expand or modify the code snip above and perhaps not use a loop.

Comment: What you have is a JavaScript object, not JSON. Your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON. You are also not "parsing" anything, you are simply traversing the data structure.

Comment: JSON is just "the way you write an object declaration in JS". There's no such thing as a "json object". It's a text format.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil: *JSON is just "the way you write an object declaration in JS"*. No, you are confusing JavaScript object literals with JSON. The two are related but not the same.

Comment: @FelixKing Well yeah, if you want to be precise I guess... Declaring an object with `{ key: value, key: value}` is a JavaScript object literal. JSON is a text file format, or a way to represent data as a text which consists of a single JavaScript object literal.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil: JSON does not contain JavaScript (object literals). JSON is a language independent data format, like XML. It was *inspired* by JavaScript, but it is not JavaScript.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil  Thank you for the clarification of the terms.  Is there anything specific I need to change in the question to make in more clear and a better question?  Does my confusion regarding the terms obscure the problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: @felixkling If there is anything I must do to change the question please let me know or make a specific suggestion.  I don't want my confusion regarding terms to obscure the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to map and filter simultaneously use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var indexes = parsed.terms.reduce(function(indexCollection, item, index) {
    if(item.label === 'number') {
        indexCollection.push(index);
    }

    return indexCollection;
}, []);
```